# function convert string to int - C

Tags: c, string, char, int

I want to scan in a string that can take at least 200 characters and then I want to **convert** the string to an `int`, so that I can print it with e.g. `printf("%d", digit)`.

How can I write a function kinda like this I've written here
(this one does not work!):

```
int main()
{

  char car[200];
  int number;
  int i,x;
  int sum = 0;

  printf("Write in number: \n");
  scanf("%c", &car);

  for (i=0; i<200; i++) {

    if (car[i] != '\0') {
      x = car[i]-'0';
      sum = sum + x;

      if (i != 0) {
        sum = sum*10;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself this question: what is the maximul value an `int` can contain ? Then think about the "at least 200 characters part" of your question.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &car);` should be `scanf("%s", car);` The largest number you can place in an int (or long) is 2^32 (2^64). Probably 200 digits will go beyond that.

Comment: The largest value an `int` can have is 2147483647. If you used an `unsigned int` you could have 4294967295. Even if you used an `unsigned long long` the largest value you could hold would be 18446744073709551615. You cannot have 200 digits without making your own data structure to represent it

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: wrong. The range of an `int` is _implementation defined. There is a minimum requirement (`+/-32767`), but no max. limit. `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` provide this range for the implementation (`limits.h`)..

Comment: @asimes: wrong see my comment above.

Comment: @Olaf, no it is not wrong. Get out a calculator and type in (2^32)-1 as well as (2^64)-1. The point is not that it might be smaller than that due to the OP's system, the point is that no built-in integer representation will contain 200 digits

Comment: @asimes: please point me where the **C standard** states that! (And I do not need a calculator for that)

Comment: Olaf is correct. There is no maximum number of digits.

Comment: @Estonia_girl Should it handle "++-++-++--+--+-+--++-+--20" as -20, which is correct mathematically, or as an error because there isn't a digit following the first sign? If you want the error behavior, you don't need a 200 byte buffer, practically speaking. Even if your `INT_MAX` was `2**127 - 1`, it would only require 41 bytes: 1 byte for the sign, 39 bytes for the magnitude, and 1 byte for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", car);
```

You need to read a string `%s` not a single char `%c`. Also char array will decay to a pointer when passed as an argument, so you shouldn't use &char.

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
scanf("%c", &car);
```

from `man scanf`:

> c
>   Matches a sequence of characters whose length is specified by the maximum field width (**default 1**); the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to char, and there  must  be  enough
>                 room  for  all the characters (**no terminating null byte is added**).  The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.  To
>   skip white space first, use an explicit space
>                 in the format.

So you're reading exactly one character, not a whole string.

Then, you rely on a terminating null byte being added, which isn't happening. Use `%199s` instead, leaving enough room for the terminating null byte.

Then, considering no `int` in this world should have enough space for numbers with 199 decimal digits, you should think about your 200 character buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is not to write such a function for educational purposes, but because you need one:

```
int number;
scanf("%d", &number);
```

does exactly that: Read one number from the input, and place it in `number`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,Start from the end of the string because units place is from right to left then increment the units place to ten's place then 100 and so on.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char input[9];
    int digit,number=0,i=1;

    printf("Enter Number:\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    digit=strlen(input)-1;
    while(digit>=0)
    {

            number=number + i*(input[digit]-'0');
            digit=digit-1;
            i=i*10;

    }
    printf("%d",number);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Close.  Suggested changes below.

Use `char car[200+1]` to "take at least 200 characters".

Use `"%200s"` rather than `"%c"` to read a string rather than a `char` and to limit its input.

```
//int main()
int main(void) {
  // char car[200];
  char car[200+1];
  int number;
  int i,x;
  int sum = 0;

  printf("Write in number: \n");
  // scanf("%c", &car);
  scanf("%200s", car);

  // for (i=0; i<200; i++) {
  for (i=0; car[i]; i++) {
    // if (car[i] != '\0'){
    x = car[i]-'0';
    // sum = sum + x;
    sum = 10*sum + x;
    // if (i != 0) { sum = sum*10; }
  }
  printf("%d\n", sum)
  return 0;
}
```

---

Unless input is like "000000000000000000000000000123", 200 digits will certainly overflow `sum`.

To detect that

```
    x = car[i]-'0';
    if (sum >= INT_MAX/10 && (sum > INT_MAX/10 || x > INT_MAX%10)) {
      x = INT_MAX;
      // maybe set an error flag
      break; 
    }
    sum = 10*sum + x;
```

---

An `int` has an maximum value of `INT_MAX` from `#include < limits.h>`.  It is *at least* 32767.  Some platforms use 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit `int` Other ranges are possible.  Let us assume a worst case of 128-bit.  That would need about 39 decimal digits.  Leaving room for a sign and terminating null character, suggest

```
char car[39+1+1];
```

Comment: You forget the terminating condition!  -- Oops...yes you have. My apologies.

Comment: You shouldn't use 200, but 199. The terminating byte must still fit!

Comment: @Marcus Müller  OP want to "take atleast 200 characters" so the buffer should be sized at least 201.  `"%200s"` is the correct format.

Comment: ah yes, you're right, if we include your edit that added `+1` to `char[200]`. Still, a 200-digit number won't fit into int.

Comment: @Marcus Müller See edit concerning many digit inputs. The "You shouldn't use 200, but 199" comment is incorrect as the answer's buffer size is 201.